# Left aligning plots but keeping actual size

Tags: r

How to save multiple plots and keep their different actual-sizes on a same page (image below). `arrangeGrob` meets my requirement on keeping the actual size of each plot but it is not possible to align them left. `plot_grid`, `ggarrange`, and `gtable` provide horizontal aligning but these functions resize the plot. 
[image]

Comment: What abt https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork ? and, mebbe `cowplot`?

Comment: Hi, as I mentioned above, plot_grid in cowplot package doesn't meet my requirement. I understand that with plot_grid, I can set rel_widths manually, but I have I want to find proper way to do that.

Comment: (didn't recognize the function name I only remember the package but hey so much for trying to help) and `patchwork`?

Comment: there _is_ very likely an ugly, manual `grid` way to accomplish this. i shall ponder it over the weekend